# Rails has_and_belongs_to_many with Many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, activemodel

I'm working on a Rails 4 app with complex associations and i cant figure out how to join one model to a parent.

Basically my apps logic is as follows

```
User
  - belongs_to :account, polymorphic: true

Developer
  - has_one :user, as: :account
  - has_and_belongs_to_many :organizations

Organization
  - has_one :user, as: :account
  - has_and_belongs_to_many :developers
```

- I decided to go this route over a STI because this allowed me to make my apps migration file cleaner and more organized

So there can be a `Developer` by itself and there can also be and `Organization` which holds many `Developers`, so i added `has_and_belongs_to_many :organizations` and `has_and_belongs_to_many :developers` to create this relationship. So everything works here in my app if i look up `User.find().account.developers` or `User.find().account.organizations` i get the associated records.

---

Now we get to the part where i am having trouble. Within my Rails app i have a model called `App`. A `Developer` can create many `Apps` by itself or a `Developer` can create and `Organization` and create many `Apps` within that `Organization` that all of the `Developers` who belong to that `Organization` have access too. I have no idea how to implement a relationship like this. Any suggestions?

---

```
Developer
  has_one :user, as: :account
  has_many :apps, as: :appable
  has_and_belongs_to_many :founding_organizations, class_name: 'Organization', foreign_key: :founder_id
  has_and_belongs_to_many :collaborating_organizations, class_name: 'Organization', foreign_key: :collaborator_id

  has_and_belongs_to_many :organizations   (Should this stay?)

Organization
       has_one :user, as: :account
  has_many :apps, as: :appable
  has_and_belongs_to_many :founders, class_name: 'Developer', association_foreign_key: :founder_id
  has_and_belongs_to_many :collaborators, class_name: 'Developer', association_foreign_key: :collaborator_id

  has_and_belongs_to_many :developers   (Should this stay?)

App
  belongs_to :appable, polymorphic: true
```

Comment: Can a developer belong to many organizations?

Comment: @Bigxiang Yes they can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/app/models/app.rb

```
App < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :appable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

/app/models/organization.rb

```
Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :founders, :class_name => 'Developer', :association_foreign_key => :founder_id, :join_table => 'founders_organizations'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :collaborators, :class_name => 'Developer', :association_foreign_key => :collaborator_id, :join_table => 'collaborators_organizations'
  has_many :apps, :as => :appable
  # Other relationships
 end
```

/app/models/developer.rb

```
Developer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :founded_organizations, :class_name => 'Organization', :foreign_key => :founder_id, :join_table => 'founders_organizations'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :collaborated_organizations, :class_name => 'Organization', :foreign_key => :collaborator_id, :join_table => 'collaborators_organizations'
  has_many :apps, :as => :appable
  # Other relationships
 end
```

Comment: I was thinking that to make it cleaner I can have an organization have many founders and many collaborators, is that possible with this setup?

Comment: No. This will only work if an organization has only one founder. Didn't you just ask me the same question last night? :)

Comment: Yes i apologize for being redundant, its just that everyday i come up with a new logic that sounds better then i have trouble implementing it. I appreciate your help tho, can we modify the above to have an organization have many founders and many collaborators or will that not even work at all?

Comment: Thanks, i updated my question with the new models at the bottom, do they look alright?

Comment: Answering your question, those lines have to be removed. Now a developer can only relate to an organization either as a founder or as a collaborator.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36214/discussion-between-ny95-and-depa)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a HABTM association. you need a join table. In Rails 4, you can add a migration file containing this:

```
create_join_table :developers, :organizations
```

Then just use:

```
Developer.find().organizations
```

or

```
Organization.find().developers
```

If you use `User.find().account`. you must get account's class first, then decide to use `developers` or `organizations`

Comment: Thanks this makes it more clear but as far as adding apps to an account or organization will this work?

Comment: I think it should work adding apps anywhere. You would better to add apps to user model, decouple it with developer or organization.